# autosearch suggestion is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, json

i am working on **autocomplete suggestion** based on **[AutoComplete plugin](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete)**. i am using html js css.Its working when i use  var currencies = ["a","b","a1","a2","a3"]; but its not working when i use **JSON RESPONSE**.When i type on the input field it gives **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined** error but it works if use **var currencies = ["a","b","a1","a2","a3"];**

```js
/**js for invoking backend service which is in json format**/

function wlCommonInit() {
  var currencies = [];

  function empautos(result) {
    WL.Logger.debug("feed retrieve successsss");
    es1(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.EmpList);
  }

  function es1(result) {
    WL.Logger.debug("Checking here");
    for (var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++) {
      currencies[i] = result[i].ENAME;
      WL.Logger.debug(currencies);
      //console
      /** ["1, Approver","1222430837 lastname, Mr. 1222430837 firstname",
      "A Bakker","A Chunekar","A Gopalan","AGD, Mr. APPROVER","APPROVER, JOURNAL","Aachen, Torben","Aafjes , B"] **/
    }
  }

  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: currencies
  });


}
```

```html
<div id="searchfield">
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="currency" class="biginput" id="autocomplete"/>
     </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the documentation of the plugin you have to transform you data into the format [{data:'', value:''}]. Basically an array of objects and each object should have the keys `data` and `value`.

So I manipulated your data like below

```
var data = [
  "1, Approver",
  "1222430837 lastname, Mr. 1222430837 firstname",
  "A Bakker",
  "A Chunekar",
  "A Gopalan",
  "AGD, Mr. APPROVER",
  "APPROVER, JOURNAL",
  "Aachen, Torben",
  "Aafjes , B"
];

data = data.map(function(item) {
    return {data: item, value: item};
});
```

**[Here is the working code.](http://jsbin.com/qowiyo/2/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: currencies = currencies.map(function(item) {
         return {data: item, value: item};

Comment: is this how i need to change

Comment: getting same error jeez "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined"

Comment: Then create a failing demo in jsbin or jsfiddle

Comment: i am using some adapter techniques here which i cant post in jfiddle